# time and datetime modules producing different result

Tags: python, datetime, time

Why gmt and utc results are different when running following code.

```
import time
import datetime

print( time.mktime(time.gmtime()))
print(datetime.datetime.utcnow().strftime("%s"))
```

**Output**:

```
1571984607.0
1571981007
```

I read many articles gmt and utc both will give same result. Why I am getting different result here.
gmt is 1 hour advance in time module when I converted it to IST.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Check out the [tour]. Here's a hint: 3600 seconds is an hour.

Comment: I wasn't able to find a solution, but it seems like `time.mktime` is factoring in DST when it shouldn't

Comment: You are comparing `.gmtime()` with `utcnow()`, what gives `time.time()`?

Comment: gmtime default argument is time.time(), even though I tested it by time.time(), both are same result. One thing I didn't under stand why exactly 1 hour difference. **1571984607−1571981007=3600**